# How to emulate Excel's automatic rounding?

Tags: excel, floating-point, rounding, precision

When Excel reports the results of a floating point calculation, it appears to round it to the correct precision based on the significant digits in the input numbers. But if I include the result in a text string, it includes the full precision, including the floating point error:

[image]

How can I get the text version to use the same rounding as Excel uses in displaying the number? I suppose I could calculate the maximum number of digits of precision of the input numbers and `round()` to that precision. Is there an easier/better way?

Using Excel 2019.

Comment: `="the result is " & TEXT(C2,"General")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `="The result is " & TEXT(C2,"@")`

This will apply the Standard-Formatting to the result.

Comment: Thank you. Comparing your answer to Ron's comment, is "@" shorthand for "General"?

Comment: Follow-up question: What if I want to preserve that rounding in the stored value, i.e., get rid of the floating point error? I can do `=value(text(C2, "@"))`. Is that the right way, or is there a more direct method?

Comment: @ treats the value as Text - I suppose it's the same like "General" - but I couldn't find a documentation. It makes no difference if you add 'Value' to the function

Comment: I meant if I want to preserve the number correctly rounded in a new cell by itself as a number.